# React - handleChange method not firing causing selected option name not to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a `<Select>` component from [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) renders a couple options to a dropdown, these options are fetched from an api call, mapped over, and the names are displayed. When I select an option from the dropdown the selected name does not appear in the box. It seems that my `handleChange` method is not firing and this is where I update the value of the schema name:

```
  handleChange = value => {
    // this is going to call setFieldValue and manually update values.dataSchemas
    this.props.onChange("schemas", value);
```

This is not updating the value seen in the dropdown after something is selected.

I'm not sure if I'm passing the right thing to the `value` prop inside the component  itself

```
   class MySelect extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          schemas: [],
          fields: [],
          selectorField: ""
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("/dataschemas").then(response => {
          this.setState({
            schemas: response.data.data
          });
          console.log(this.state.schemas);
        });
      }

      handleChange = value => {
        // this is going to call setFieldValue and manually update values.dataSchemas
        this.props.onChange("schemas", value);
        const schema = this.state.schemas.find(
          schema => schema.name === value.target.value
        );
        if (schema) {
          axios.get("/dataschemas/2147483602").then(response => {
            this.setState({
              fields: response.data.fields
            });
            console.log(this.state.fields);
          });
        }
      };

      updateSelectorField = e => {
        this.setState({ selectorField: e.target.value });
      };

      handleBlur = () => {
        // this is going to call setFieldTouched and manually update touched.dataSchemas
        this.props.onBlur("schemas", true);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div style={{ margin: "1rem 0" }}>
            <label htmlFor="color">
              DataSchemas -- triggers the handle change api call - (select 1){" "}
            </label>
            <Select
              id="color"
              options={this.state.schemas}
              isMulti={false}
              value={this.state.schemas.find(
                ({ name }) => name === this.state.name
              )}
              getOptionLabel={({ name }) => name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            />
            {!!this.props.error && this.props.touched && (
              <div style={{ color: "red", marginTop: ".5rem" }}>
                {this.props.error}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

I have linked [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/l2ok58lvl7) showing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handleChange` function you are trying to access `value.target.value`. If you console.log(value) at the top of the function, you will get:

```
{
    id: "2147483603"
    selfUri: "/dataschemas/2147483603"
    name: "Book Data"
}
```

This is the value that `handChange` is invoked with. Use `value.name` instead of `value.target.value`.